# How can I pop up a window containing a star rating system, so a user can input his rating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I am building a project and I want to implement this:

1. a user clicks on a button
2. a pop up window appears showing star rating
3. the user enters his rating in the pop up
4. then I get the inputted value

anyone knows how can I implement this?thank you

Comment: Please try by yourself first. SO is not a free outsourcing service

Comment: What have you tried so far? Rating system wwidget code and modal popup codes are everywhere

Comment: SO is for helping each other, if you don't want to help, nobody is obliging you to do so, but anyway thanks for your time @RegisPortalez

Comment: It's for helping people who try. Not to provide free code for others

Comment: Hi @mlegg, I tried to use prompt but the problem is that I don't want the users to input any value, so I am trying to use a form and popping up it

Comment: I don't think that I understand then. You want a popup and then offer people a rating system on it but you don't want them to rate you? Or do you just want your rating to popup?

Comment: If I am not showing a block of code it does not mean that I did not try, I tried different approaches and showing code for different approaches will not help in answering my question. btw I don't need a free code, I only need an approach to this question, what function should I use and how, so please don't assume something that you don't know @RegisPortalez

Comment: I want them to rate in the popup and get the value @mlegg

Comment: Provided an answer (sort of). Please try to narrow the scope though

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

Question is too broad, but here are a few elements:
- you dont want a popup, because it's ugly, and browser often block them.

If you control the code of the rating form (same domain, same security level, and same code base) I guess a modal is the way to go (templating systems like knockout or angular will help you a lot). Then you can get the result with simple javascript (synchronously).

If you don't, a iframe is probably a good solution, and you can communicate with it via postmessage API, or websockets, or any other solution you can find by searching for this specific question.